# Graphical SSH tool like superputty for centos7 XFCE

Tags: centos, ssh, xfce, putty

Could you please suggest some graphical tools like super-putty or "gnome connection manager" for Centos7 please. Thanks.

edit : I want tabbed user interface and gui tool which will store username, server name and password and double clicking will open the particular server. I am using XFCE environment under Centos7. 
If you could please advise me the free GUI ssh softwares for CentOS7 that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What does it have to do?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I want to connect to multiple linux terminals. I want to store the servers under folders with username and password and open the terminal as I need one.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with **Gnome Connection Manager**
https://linoxide.com/tools/gnome-gui-remote-management/

Or you can check PAC Manager, but needs to be installed from rpm package.
Below links can be helpful:

https://www.xfce-look.org/p/1130778/

https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=49960

http://blog.bentgeorge.com/?p=161

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that is for ubuntu (sudo apt )

Comment: @ForeverLearner I added other option to the answere.

Comment: Thanks and upvoted but I have heard PAC manager is not maintained anymore and is not secure. I was unable to install the fork too.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and I found Asbru-CM.  https://asbru-cm.net  I've been using it  a couple of days.